# cumulative SQL query execution time *MUCH* lower then EF ExecuteStoreCommands

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

so I've been profiling this MVC application and I've noticed that certain queries are slow, so naturally I've profiled both my application and database.

These are the findings:

Sum of all DB calls according to MSSQL profiler is **48ms** for 29 SQL commands.
That seems reasonable.

EDIT: each of those 29 calls are followed by exec sp_reset_connection command (not sure if relevant).

Here is the odd part, application profiling says this:

Entity framework's

```
internal virtual DbDataReader ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

took **578ms** to execute. Or let me break it down even more.

```
 private ObjectResult<T> GetResults(MergeOption? forMergeOption)
{
  this.QueryState.ObjectContext.AsyncMonitor.EnsureNotEntered();
  IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy = DbProviderServices.GetExecutionStrategy(this.QueryState.ObjectContext.Connection, this.QueryState.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace);
  if (executionStrategy.RetriesOnFailure && this.QueryState.EffectiveStreamingBehaviour)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings.ExecutionStrategy_StreamingNotSupported((object) executionStrategy.GetType().Name));
  else
    return executionStrategy.Execute<ObjectResult<T>>((Func<ObjectResult<T>>) (() => this.QueryState.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction<ObjectResult<T>>((Func<ObjectResult<T>>) (() => this.QueryState.GetExecutionPlan(forMergeOption).Execute<T>(this.QueryState.ObjectContext, this.QueryState.Parameters)), executionStrategy, false, !this.QueryState.EffectiveStreamingBehaviour)));
}
```

out of 578ms takes 552ms.

And if I break it down even more.

```
public ObjectResult<T> Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
    {
      EntityUtil.CheckArgumentMergeOption(mergeOption);
      return this.GetResults(new MergeOption?(mergeOption));
    }
```

**397ms**

and GetEnumerator takes **155ms**, that method invokes Lazy method "CreateValue" etc...

I'll stop here.

These execution times are measured by Jetbrains DotTrace.

I do realize that having EF inherently means "some" overhead. But this seems to be excessive.

EF 6.1.2,
SQL server 2012 Standard

Am I asking too much? Am I being unreasonable when expecting "some" overhead, not 12x overhead?

Or am I simply not approaching this the correct way?

Best regards,
T.

Comment: Well, you're comparing apples and oranges for one. Entity Framework does work outside of just querying the database. It's got to instantiate objects, set up all the relationships, initialize all the object tracking stuff. None of this is cheap and I don't think 500ms is really all that bad when 29 queries are involved. That's quite a lot of queries for a single page-load. Yes, there's going to be overhead with any ORM. If your question is how efficient is EF, then you need to profile with other ORM choices, not against straight SQL.

Comment: Hi Chris. I'm not actually comparing that, I was just surprised by the magnitude of difference between queries and complete EF operation required to execute them. Overhead was, like I mentioned, expected as that "overhead" is used for the application object creation, etc, just like you said. I'll consolidate those queries in something more simple view or stored procedure and get back with the findings.

Comment: Actually, you didn't mention how your test was structured. Does the 48ms just for the SQL factor in transport time? Remember the roundtrip to the database takes some amount of time and depending on network latency involved, something in the range of 100-200ms just to send the queries and another 100-200ms to receive the results wouldn't be abnormal. If that were the case then you're only looking at roughly 200ms of processing time for EF, which is only a 4x increase over straight SQL.

Comment: I don't think networking or topology is an issue. This is a test on dev machine. Everything is local.

Comment: Okay, but that then skews things in an opposite direction. Local development profiling is all but useless, as your desktop class development machine is no match for an actual web server and IIS Express is single-threaded and not optimized. Real IIS will be able to run much faster, especially on server-hardware. Development profiling is only useful to make sure there's no huge, out of the ordinary bottlenecks anywhere. Otherwise, save your profiling for your production server or a facsimile thereof, such as stage or QA.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework by default does much more than just executing the query and also it serializes and de-serializes the data, the first time you run any EF command it takes much more time than subsequent calls, do a worm up call before measuring the call time.

Some validations made by EF are being done again on the DB such as data integrity.

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

This will reduce significantly the EF calls time, but will also reduce functionality.

Try digging a bit more as depending on the case changing the default configuration values can change significantly the time for each call.

Finally Yes EF as a hit on performance but removes lots of issues during the development faze, and servers are cheep and programmers expensive.

Comment: AutodetectChangesEnabled is false already in this setup, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: It was just an example of the changes that are possible to do on the Configuration, the least recommended one and also one that makes big changes is the ValidateOnSaveEnabled it is not recommended to disable it but it will be closer to the direct SQL call. for just plain calls the buggiest difference will be the warm-up call as it is there that EF creates the object constructors for the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm little bit late, but keep in mind profiler has it's own overhead as well and it depends on profiling type. For Sampling it's small, for Timeline little bigger, then goes Tracing, and most heavy is line-by-line. So to get most accurate absolute function execution time you should use Sampling.

However in dotTrace 6.1 there is an option to profile client-side SQL interactions in Timeline mode, including connection opening time, execution and results transport overhead. So you could try it to find out where the problem is.